# How to specify username in ClientCredentials (Basic) while calling SAP PI service from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, sap-pi, sap-xi

**I need to use http not https**

The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.
Parameter name: via

What I have to change?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using configuration file I need to switch from:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding>
        <httpsTransport />
    </binding>
<customBinding>
```

to

```
<customBinding>
    <binding>
        <httpTransport />
    </binding>
<customBinding>
```

Comment: I need to log in via basic to HTTP